# What's wrong with my UDP client (android)?

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp

```
final int SERVERPORT = 5902;
String SERVERIP = "HereTheIPOfMyPC"; //I have tried with "127.0.0.1", "10.0.2.2" and my local IP
CharSequence tosend = "Probandooooooooooo";
try {
       DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
       InetAddress local = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
       byte[] message = tosend.toString().getBytes();
       DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message,message.length, local, SERVERPORT);
       s.send(p);
       s.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I don't receive the message :S

Note: I have a UDP server on my pc and I try the app on a device.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing with the addresses. If the sever and client are on different boxes, "127.0.0.1", ie. localhost, is not going to work for sure.

Comment: And, What should I put?

Comment: You have to use the network-accessible IP that the server is actually listening on.

Comment: Also, call `tosend.toString().getBytes()` by itself and then set `msg_length` to the length of the `byte[]` array. Do not call `tosend.toString()` twice and set `msg_length` to the length of the `String`, which may be different than the length of the `byte[]` depending on which characters are used.  Remember that Java strings are UTF-16 encoded, but `getBytes()` does not return a UTF-16 encoded `byte[]` array unless you explicitly ask it to (which you are not).

Comment: Ok I changed it but still not working :S

Comment: Assuming you the physical networking side of things is all working (i.e using the correct IP to communicate to your computer) consider downloading and installing [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to analyse what gets sent/what happens when your packet is sent. I find this tool very useful when debugging networked applications.

Comment: Ok finally I did it, all I need is create an AsyncTask
Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Does the datagram arrive if you remove the close() call?

If so, you want to look into SO_LINGER socket option, so that the socket lingers while there are still datagrams to process.

Answer (score 0):

I think you testing the application in emulator, if it in the case lets check

[how to use emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)

U have to forward the port from local actual pc port to virtual emulator port.

U cant access the PC from emulator through localhost or 127.0.0.1 IP u have to use actual PC IP connected to LAN.

if u using real device also check wether ur device actually reach your PC through particular ip.

If u try through LAN it will work. If u trying in WAN environment it wont work.

```
(Check NAT for more Details).
```